# Assigning a variable to a specific dimension of a jagged array

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

I am learning C# by making a tetris game bellow is a 3d Array that represents a tetromino and its four rotations and I would like to assign a variable to one of the 2d arrays inside. I am used to javascript and cannot figure out the syntax.

```
           int[][][] T = new int[][][]
            {
               new int[][] {
                    new int[]{0,1,0},
                    new int[]{1,1,1},
                    new int[]{0,0,0}
                },
                new int[][]{
                    new int[]{0,1,0},
                    new int[]{0,1,1},
                    new int[]{0,1,0}
                },
                new int[][]{
                    new int[]{0,0,0},
                    new int[]{1,1,1},
                    new int[]{0,1,0},
                },
                new int[][]{
                    new int[]{0,1,0},
                    new int[]{1,1,0},
                    new int[]{0,1,0}
                }
            };

            int position = 0; 
            //this is what i would like to do but it throws a error
            int[][] activePiece = T[position];

            //example in javascript
            //const activePiece = T[position]
            //and activePiece would equal
            //[[0,1,0]
            //[1,1,1]
            //[0,0,0]]
```

Comment: it is actually correct and should not throw an error, what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I just pasted you exact code in here. [check it out](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lrBT9C)

Comment: Pasted code is working for me, I am getting the equivalent of the commented lines. What problem are you having then?

Comment: opps I figured it out thank you guys